# Результат запроса group by по столбцам

Tags: mysql, sql-server

После применения group by имею таблицу такого формата:

| Товар | Категория | к-во |
| --- | --- | --- |
| хлеб | Продан | 2 |
| хлеб | На складе | 3 |
| Каша | Продан | 5 |
| Каша | На складе | 1 |
| Вода | Продан | 7 |
| Соль | На складе | 10 |

Как из неё можно сделать таблицу формата

| Товар | На складе | Продан |
| --- | --- | --- |
| хлеб | 3 | 2 |
| Каша | 1 | 5 |
| Вода | 0 | 7 |
| Соль | 10 | 0 |

Я могу создать уникальный список товаров и заджойнить значений, но надеюсь, что есть вариант проще

Comment: Это куда-то в сторону `pivot table` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Comment: И для MS SQL Server вроде готовые конструкции SQL есть https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN cat = 'Продан' THEN value else 0 END) as [продан], ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select   Товар,
  sum (case when Категория = 'На складе' then value else 0 end) as На складе
  sum (case when Категория = 'Продан' then value else 0 end) as Продан
from     table
group by Товар
```

думаю может так?

Comment: "else 0" излишне, можно просто "sum (case when "Категория" = 'На складе' then value end)"

Comment: а зачем там после then ставится слово value ? какую роль он имеет? спасибо :)

Comment: вместо value нужно подставить имя столбца по которому будет считаться сумма